# Generic abstract class extending generic class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

It's likely that I'm not using the correct terminology here, so please excuse me in that case.

I have a class:

```
public class HandleArtist extends ArtistDAO
```

that handles database changes for the `Artist` entity/type. There are many similar classes with the same structure:

- `HandleAlbum extends AlbumDAO`, for `Album` entity/type
- `HandleTrack extends TrackDAO`, for `Track` entity/type
- etc.

All those "Handle"-classes have (or should at least have) basically the same methods. In order to make sure that I really have the same methods and structure, I thought that making an `abstract` base class that I then extend all "handle"-classes to, could be a good idea.

So I tried to make an abstract class like:

```
public abstract class Handler<T1> extends <T2>
```

which didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot extend from a type parameter, because it's not a `Class`. Could you use composition instead of inheritance in your `Handler`s --  why do they need to extend the DAOs? If you'd share some example code then you could get better suggestions.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html

Comment: Try just `public abstract class Handler<T> {...}`

Comment: @Mick: Ok. Thanks. I'll go for using composition instead - there's no real need for me to extend the DAOs. If the answer is that it's not posible to do what I described in the post, you could add your comment as an answer instead and I'll mark it as a solution.